# How do I get the current pk that is being accessed?

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

So I'm trying to make a GET request to get the students from a School. and I have a nested viewset. What I'm trying to do for example is get website/schools/1/students. So I need to get the PK which in this case would be 1 without hardcoding in 1, because there is more than 1 school in my database. I have the the schools attached to students based on School ID's. For example school with pk =1 has an ID of 4289.

```
class SchoolStudentsViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    List all the students from a specific school.
    """

    queryset = Student.objects.filter(school_id=pk.id, name='School of Edumacation')
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firgured it out!

```
class SchoolStudentsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
"""
List all the students from a specific school.
"""
def list(self, request, school_pk=None, **kwargs):

    queryset = Student.objects.filter(school__pk=school_pk)
    serializer = StudentSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)
```